# Deploying a DataFormWebPart

Tags: 2010, web-part, data-form-web-part

I have a page with a DataFormWebPart setup to display some data from a subweb. The page is setup ok, the webpart is working. In my solution, I need to create the subweb (that's already working ok) and then place the DataFormWebPart on the default page of the current site.

I was trying to do this declaratively via a module, but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried this approach:

```
<Module Name="MyOrgPages">
<File Path="MyOrgPages\Home.aspx" Url="SitePages/Home.aspx">
  <AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder="0" WebPartZoneID="Left">
    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <webPart>...</webPart>
    ]]>
  </AllUsersWebPart>
</File>
```

But SharePoint keeps complaining it doesn't understand the content of the webpart. I got the  contents by exporting the webpart to a .webpart file and copying the contents of that file.

So is this actually the correct way to do this, and if so: what could be the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ah stupid. You need to include `<webParts> </webParts>` inside the CDATA bit, otherwise it doesn't work.